# Modal inside XMLHttpRequest server not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using XMLHttpRequest to update a container of cards without having to refresh the page. Here is the script i use:

```js
<script>

    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("request_queue").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "server.php", true);
        xhttp.send();
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            loadXMLDoc();
            // 1sec
        },1000);

        window.onload = loadXMLDoc;
    </script>
```

```html
    <div id="request_queue">

    </div>
```

In the server file, i run the php query to display the card contents but i also have a dynamic modal for each card. I placed it inside the query loop. The modal shows up but it also disappears right after. I dont know where i should put the modal code. Here is what is inside the server.php

```html
<?php
    include "../db_config.php";

    $status = "Received";
?>

<div class="row flex justify-content-center">

<?php
    $queryReqList ="SELECT * FROM request";
    $sqlReq = mysqli_query($conn, $queryReqList);
    while ($requestresults = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlReq)) {

        $id = $requestresults['request_id'];

        if ($requestresults['request_status'] == $status){
        ?>
<?php


?>
    <div class="card" style="width: 30rem; margin: 1em;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $requestresults['user_num']?></p>
            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $requestresults['user_address']?></p>
            
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="reqID" value="<?php echo id; ?>">
                <button name="request-accept" class="btn btn-success float-end m-2">Accept</button>
                
               <!-- Modal button-->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#DeclineModal<?php echo $id;?>">
  Decline
</button>
                
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="DeclineModal<?php echo $id;?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<?php
        }

        
    }

?>

</div>
```

Comment: `The modal shows up but it also disappears right after`... because you've set it up to load and then reload every second - that's what setInterval does. It's not clear why you used that.

Comment: i just want the div to automatically update to display new entries coming from the database without having to click refresh. is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Yes but a) don't run it every second as you could overwhelm the server, and b) if you don't want it to keep replacing the existing HTML then your request could send the server the ID of the last entry it received and then the server could send only ones whose ID is bigger than that, and you could append that to the current data instead of overwriting it.